# clearInterval() Undefined Error After Using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this isn't supposed to be inline, but YUI library's dialogs force me to. My issue is that whenever I hover over this div, the margin-left scroll activated but it does not stop when I move the mouse out of the div. The JS console reports that:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: timerID is not defined

And here's the code:

```
<div class="span1" onmouseover="
            var timerID;
             $(document).ready(function(){              
                    timerID = setInterval(scrollLeft, 10);

                    function scrollLeft(){
                        $('.inner_wrapper').animate({
                            marginLeft: '-=30px'
                        });
                    }
             });
             " onmouseout="clearInterval(timerID)">
        </div>
```

EDIT: The thing is that I can NOT run SCRIPT tags inside dialogs (they are already created via scripts, which filter any javascript besides inline one like onmouseover and onmouseout). So your suggestions of encapsulating the onmouseover and onmouseout handles in a single function will not work in this case.

Comment: try setInterval("scrollLeft()",10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a scope problem. You variable `timerID` is not visible in onmouseout.

Generally it is a good idea, to put stuff into a function instead of clobbering it all into the attributes. This avoids all these scope-problems. And it's an even better idea to use handlers instead of the `on-...`-atrributes.

Define your function outside the `onmouseover` attribute and call another function in the `mouseout` which clears it.

Something like this (to avoid nasty global varaibles)

```
var handler = (function(){
    var timerID;
    function scrollLeft(){
       $('.inner_wrapper').animate({
           marginLeft: '-=30px'
       });
    }
    return{
      mouseover:function(){              
            timerID = setInterval(scrollLeft, 10);
         },
      mouseout:function(){
            clearInterval(timerID);
      }
    }
})();
```

and then

```
<div class="span1" onmouseover="handler.mouseover()" onmouseout="handler.mouseout()">
```

or even better, bind the handlers directly via:

```
$('.span1').hover(function() {
    timerID  = setInterval(scrollLeft, 10); //mouseover
}, function() {
    clearInterval(timerID); //mouseout
});
```

As of new jQuery 1.7, `.on()`should be preferred.

Comment: The thing is that I can not run external javascript, be it in its own Script tag or in a loaded js file. I only have the option of using inline JS like in onmouseover and onmouseout. If there is a way to share a variable between these two attributes, this would do the trick. (like a super-global variable of some kind, valid for the whole document)

Comment: @user1364793 Well, thats kind of a problem I guess. I don't know any solution for that case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timerID = null;

    function scrollleft() {
        $('.inner_wrapper').animate({
            marginLeft: '-=30px'
        });
    }
    $('div.span1').hover(function() {
        timerID  = setInterval(scrollLeft, 10);
    }, function() {
        clearInterval(timerID);
    });
});​
```

and make you html like

```
<div class="span1"></div>
```

If you use `.on('hover')` then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timerID = null;

    function scrollleft() {
        $('.inner_wrapper').animate({
            marginLeft: '-=30px'
        });
    }

    $('div.span1').on('hover', function(e) {
        if(e.type == 'mouseenter') {
           timerID  = setInterval(scrollLeft, 10);
        } else {
            clearInterval(timerID);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: The thing is that I can not separate the Javascript from the HTML. I know this is coding standards and better markup, but I am using a library for dialogs that only allows running of scripts when they are inline (e.g. in onmouseover) and not externally (in external js file or surrounded with a Script tag).

Answer (score 1):

It is not good to mix up your markup and JavaScript. Split them and work separately as follows.

*HTML:*

```
<div class="span1"></div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var timerID = null;

function scrollLeft() {
    $('.inner_wrapper').animate({
        marginLeft: '-=30px'
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".span1").hover(function() {
        timerID = setInterval(scrollLeft, 10);
    }, function() {
        clearInterval(timerID);
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said in my edited question, I can not use JS outside inline attributes like onmouseover and onmouseout.

Answer (score 1):

timerID is defined in onmouseover, but not in onmouseout.

So what you can do is following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var scrollLeft = function(){
        $('.inner_wrapper').animate({
            marginLeft: '-=30px'
        });
   }; 

   var timerID;
   $(document).ready(function(){ 

       $("#timer").mouseover(function() {

            timerID = setInterval(scrollLeft, 10);


       }).mouseout(function() {
            clearInterval(timerID)
       }); 

   }); 

</script>

<div class="span1" id="timer"> </div>
```

Comment: I am forced to use inline JS, so this is not an option for me. I need a way to run a the function with the onmouseover attribute and stop it with the onmouseout attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
var timerID;
```

variable is defined as a local variable inside the `onmouseover` handler, so the `onmouseout` handler doesn't know about it.

Declare it either as a global variable, or better - encapsulate it into an object, which will contain `timerID` as a field and `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers as methods.