# Increment Value over a Duration on Update

Tags: javascript, html, increment

I'm trying to make a script to increment a number to the selected number on every select change. For example, if the user selects 30, I want the number to increase at a rate of 30 values per second so it reaches 30 in one second.

I don't know what went wrong, but when executing this script, it only increments on the first page load but with no value change.

https://jsfiddle.net/User1010/b7znc3fL/

```
var valueElement = document.getElementById('value');

var option = document.getElementById('option');

var start     = 0;
var end       = parseFloat(option.innerHTML);
var duration  = 1000; // In milliseconds (divide by 1000 to get seconds).
var framerate = 50;    // In milliseconds (divide by 1000 to get seconds).

var toAdd = ( ( end - start ) * framerate ) / duration;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
var currentValue = parseFloat(valueElement.innerHTML);

if (currentValue >= end) {
  clearInterval(interval);
return;
}

valueElement.innerHTML = (!isNaN(currentValue) == true ? (currentValue +   toAdd).toFixed(2) : toAdd);
 }, framerate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be overthinking this task. I also found there were errors and things to change in the console and the **JSFiddle**. For example, there is no element with the name option.

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css-js/html-js-dom-animation/p/animating-dom-with-setinterval 
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-challenge-stopwatch/6144204027232256

### Let's start with something basic: A Stopwatch

1. Define variables for better convenience, for better, more common practice, and for higher efficiency

   - A variable that can be called `counterEl` initializing the span element using `document.getElementById()` on the id 'daily'.
   - A variable that can be called `selectEl` initializing the select element using `document.getElementById()` on the id 'value'.
   - A type null variable that can be called `currentTime` which will turn `counterEl` into a `float` data type by calling `parseFloat()` on `countEl.textContent`.
   - A type null variable called `stopwatch` that will be initialized when you use `setInterval`.

[I also used the linking Stack Overflow question for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880415/clearinterval-undefined-error-after-using-setinterval)

2. Add an event listener to the select element for every time its value changes like so:  `selectElement.addEventListener("change", myFunction);`
3. Create a global function `resetStopwatch() {}`

   - Set `countEl.textContent` to 0.
   - Just for good measure, set `currentTime` to 0 as well.
   - `stopwatch = window.setInterval(countUp, 1000);`
4. Create the global `countUp` function

Everything here is explained in the comments.

```
// Turns the value into a float so it can be incremented and compared (textContent is a string)
currentTime = parseFloat(seconds.textContent);
// Add 1 second every time function is called
seconds.textContent = currentTime + 1;
if (seconds.textContent >= selectElement.value) {
window.clearInterval(stopwatch); // Stops the stopwatch if the  seconds 
reached the selected option 
console.log("My time has been cleared");
}
```

### Now let's slightly tweak this to make it a 'reverse stopwatch'

In the `setInterval`, you want it to increment that many in one second, so you would change the invocation to

```
 stopwatch = window.setInterval(countUp, 1000/incrementRate.value);
```

Use *my* JS Fiddle for guidance in solving your problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/404_Error/z0t4spob/

Comment: Hi Varun, thanks for your help. My idea actually is, that it should reset the value to 0 once the select Option is changed. Like i select 10, it should run from 0 to 10 in 1 second. When i Change the select value to 30. it should run from 0 to 30 in 1 second.

Comment: @User1010, Okay, I see. I edited my post to better answer your question. I am still working on it, but I still need to work a few things out before the problem is completely fixed, so bear with me, and I hope we both can solve this puzzle soon!

Comment: I have edited the post again, and am extremely close to completing the solution. Right now, I am tinkering with the `countup` function because the console displays `stopwatch` is not defined after the selected options value is reached and the stopwatch continues to increment.

Comment: Hi, again, user1010, I have edited my post to give the solution to your problem, let me know if there is anything else you need or don't understand.

Comment: Hi Varun, thanks for your perservance, very nice from you. I actually didnt saw your tweak but i now have implemented it in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to bind a change event handler to your select/option. 
Reference [MDN's Event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) on adding this to your script to handle the changes and update of the value.

Just a heads up, if you want to use a framework like jQuery, the process and script can be simplified drastically.